# ibox to be displayed when condition is met

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have create a pop up modal in worker portal where once login it will pop up and ask the worker that, do you want to extend your contract or not. Whether they answer Yes or No, it will store in database table. I also create a box to display in dashboard and this box will display their survey response on the dashboard. Now I want to display the box only for the worker who has answered to the survey and if a worker not yet answered to the survey, I do not want to display the ibox. Can you guys help me to find solution as I am quite new in PHP and jQuery

This is my code for the ibox

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="ibox">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Your Survey Decision:</h5> <span class="label label-primary" id="surveyDecision"></span>
                    <div class="ibox-tools">
                        <a class="collapse-link" href="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <h5>Click the button below to change your decision</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateSurveyDecision">
                        Click here
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code for check contract renewal and status indicating they have answered to the query or not. If status is 1 then they have answered to the query and 0 for those who haven't answered to the query

```
function checkContractRenewal() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data/fn_getData.php?mod=contractrenewal",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status && data.contractrenewal.response_id == null) {
                var contractrenewal = data.contractrenewal;
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var contractEndDate = new Date(contractrenewal.contract_end_date);
                var year = contractEndDate.getFullYear();
                var month = String(contractEndDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
                var day = String(contractEndDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');

                txtContractEndDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                $('#txtContractEndDate').val(txtContractEndDate);

                console.log("Contract End Date: " + txtContractEndDate);

                var diffMonths = (contractEndDate.getFullYear() - currentDate.getFullYear()) * 12 +
                    contractEndDate.getMonth() - currentDate.getMonth(); // Calculate months difference

                if (diffMonths > 0 && diffMonths <= 6) {
                    $('#contractRenewalSurveyModal').modal('show');
                    $('#monthsText').text(diffMonths);
                    $('#contractEndDateText').text(txtContractEndDate);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Failed to get Contract Renewal Date. Error Msg: " + data.custMsg);

                $('#responseId').val(data.contractrenewal.response_id);
                $('#contractEndDate').val(data.contractrenewal.contract_end_date);
                $('#surveyDecision').html(data.contractrenewal.response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am expecting the box displayed to those worker have answered to the query and those worker who not yet answered to the query, I do not want the box to be displayed

Comment: add a data attribute to your `#surveyDecision` and pass PHP var which stores worker's survey response status

Comment: $('#surveyDecision').html(data.contractrenewal.response). This is the one but this is to display the worker response. But in my case I do not want to display the entire box for the worker who has not done the survey yet

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand your text, I did not add the data attribute just now. Now it is working. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: If it helped then let me post it as answer.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Hi Nico, I actually use this method $("#surveyDecisionBox").hide(); and passed pass PHP var so the box will be displayed to those worker have answered to the query and those worker who not yet answered to the query, the box to be displayed will not be displayed

Comment: Please add all clarification (including your attempts to resolve the problem) to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

So you can add a data attribute to your `#surveyDecision` and pass PHP var which stores worker's survey response status. For example -

HTML

```
<span class="label label-primary" id="surveyDecision" data-survey-status="<?php echo $var_storing_response_status ?>"></span>
```

and in your js

JS

```
var surveyStatus = $('#surveyDecision').data('survey-status');
```

So you can add a condition if survey_status is 1 (answered) then box will be displayed if 0 (unanswered) then hidden.

Comment: Hi Adi, actually ya, what I do is I give name to the ibox like this <div class="col-lg-12" id="surveyDecisionBox"> and in the function code I add this code

if (data.contractrenewal.response_id == null) {

                            $("#surveyDecisionBox").hide();

Comment: @Puvan yes what you provided works as well. It's a personal preference which you would like to choose string concatenation or template literals

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your output